# Python for google.datalab.storage - Checking for successful file copy

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Within Google Cloud Storage Bucket, I'm trying to move a file from it's original folder to the archived folder. Once the file move is 'successfully' completed, I want to then delete the file from it's original folder.

```
## Assigning the bucket to the bucket object
bucket = storage.Bucket(<Bucket_Name>)

## Enumerating and finding the required file object in the bucket and 
##assigning that to my_file object
for obj in bucket.objects():
 if obj.key.find(<file_name>) > 0:
 my_file = obj
 print(my_file.key)

## Taking the current timestamp
timestamp = str(datetime.now())

## Copying the file to the new location
my_file.copy_to( <archive folder> + <file name> + <timestamp>)
```

I now want to check if the "my_file.copy_to()" has executed successfully or not before I want to delete the file object. How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [time_created](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.time_created) or the [exists](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.exists) properties from the returned Blob object.